# Java: How do I get these two methods into one?

Tags: java, methods

In our assignment we are only allowed to use one method. I didn't know about that and I wrote two. So I wanted to ask, if its somehow possible to integrate the function of my neighbourconditions method into the life method. I tried, but I don't know how to initialize my int neighbors. Look at the following code:

```
public static String[] life(String[] dish) {
    String[] newGen = new String[dish.length];

    //TODO: implement this function
    for (int line = 0; line < dish.length; line++) { // for loop going through each line
        newGen[line] = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dish[line].length(); i++) { // loops through every character in the line
            String top = ""; // neighbours on the top
            String middle = ""; // neighbors on the same line
            String down = ""; // neighbors down
            if (i == 0){
                if(line == 0){
                    top = null;
                } else {
                    top = dish[line-1].substring(i, i+2);
                }
                middle = dish[line].substring(i + 1, i +2);
                if(line == dish.length -1){
                    down = null;
                } else {
                    down = dish[line + 1].substring(i, i + 2);
                }
            } else if (i == dish[line].length() - 1){
                if(line == 0){
                    top = null;
                } else {
                    top = dish[line - 1].substring(i - 1, i + 1);
                }
                middle = dish[line].substring(i - 1, i);
                if(line == dish.length - 1){
                    down = null;
                } else {
                    down = dish [line + 1].substring(i - 1, i + 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (line == 0){
                    top = null;
                } else {
                    top = dish[line - 1].substring(i - 1, i + 2);
                }
                middle = dish[line].substring(i - 1, i) + dish[line].substring(i+1, i+2);
                if (line == dish.length - 1){
                    down = null;
                } else {
                    down = dish[line + 1].substring(i - 1, i + 2);
                }
            }

            int neighbors = neighbourconditions(top, middle, down);
            if (neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3){ // neighbours < 2 or >3 neighbors -> they die
                newGen[line] += "o";
            } else if (neighbors == 3){
                newGen[line] += "x"; // neighbours exactly 3 -> they spawn/live
            } else {
                newGen[line] += dish[line].charAt(i); // 2 neighbours -> stay
            }
        }
    }
    return newGen;
}

// helpmethod with three arguments and the conditions
public static int neighbourconditions(String top, String middle, String down) {
    int counter = 0;
    if (top != null) { // if no one's on top
        for (int x = 0; x < top.length(); ++x) {
            if (top.charAt(x) == 'x') {
                counter++; // count if an organism's here
            }
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < middle.length(); ++x) {
        if (middle.charAt(x) == 'x') {  // two organisms, one on each side
            counter++; // count if an organism's here
        }
    }
    if (down != null) { // if no one's down
        for (int x = 0; x < down.length(); ++x) {
            if (down.charAt(x) == 'x') { // each neighbour down
                counter++; // count if an organism's here
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I don't know either.  The return types of your two methods are very different.  What is the logic behind each method?

Comment: You only call `getNeighbors` once in `life()`. What's the problem with just copying the code of `getNeighbors` and pasting it instead of that single call?

Comment: `int neighbors = counter;`

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong code, my bad. I edited it

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand but by reading your title / question / code all you have to do is copy past your code

Comment: Why don't you copy the second method call to the first one and instead of `counter` use `neighbors`?

Comment: Hint: tell the person giving such (sorry) **insane** instructions to get a grip on reality. Pushing **all code** into a single method is the absolute opposite of **good practice**. Of course, you want *one* method as entry point to the functionality, but that one method should happily use many other smaller helper methods. Rest assured: your code is **not** human comprehendable as it stands right now - and trying to force all of that into a single method is a good way to drive you crazy. In other words: if you would present the above in a code review, I would send you home ...

Comment: to do **major** refactorings immediately - I wouldnt even look at such code for 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I will show this to him :)

Comment: Note: you can simplify your `neighbourconditions` method anyway, by making it just take 1 parameter, and adding the result of calling it 3 times: `neighbourconditions(top) + neighbourconditions(middle) + neighbourconditions(down)`.

Comment: @JavaJoker204 And in case your teacher has doubts - suggest to him to get a copy of "Clean code" by Robert Martin ... and to study that in depth. Keep in mind that *real* code is written for **human readers**. And when you teach programming, you should not only focus on "content" (like algorithms, syntax, ...) but on **form**. Because *form* is what distinguishes a hacker from a professional programmer.

Comment: @JavaJoker204 "I will show this to him" Consider that if what he is asking you to do seems to be counter to good practice, the way you've approached the problem in the first place might be wrong. See if you can solve the problem in a different way, and the second method might be unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial answer to this question is to copy and paste the code from the method into the body of the other method. If you're using an IDE, you can use the in-built refactoring tools to inline the method (e.g. <kbd>ctrl-alt-n</kbd>, in intellij).

But this is the sort of behavior that makes future generations curse your name. It makes for nasty, unreadable, unmaintainable code. Don't do it. As GhostCat pointed out in comments, you should be looking to make methods *smaller*, not bigger.

Take a step back, and consider whether you're approaching the problem in the right way. Look for repeating patterns in the existing code, to see if you can simplify it. Or, sometimes, consider that you've just taken the wrong approach in the first place, and so you need to find an alternative approach.

---

As far as I can work out, all you're trying to do is to count the number of `x`s in the 8 cells immediately surrounding the current position.

You don't need all of this code to do that. You could simply do:

```
for(int row = 0; row < dish.length; row++){ // each row
  for(int col = 0; col < dish[row].length(); col++){ // each char in the row

    int neighbors = 0;
    for (int r = Math.max(row - 1, 0); r < Math.min(row + 2, dish.length); ++r) {
      for (int c = Math.max(col - 1, 0); c < Math.min(col + 2, dish[row].length()); ++c) {
        // Don't count (row, col).
        if (r == row && c == col) continue;

        if (dish[r].charAt(c) == 'x') ++neighbors;
      }
    }

    //here ends the interesting part for you
    if(neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3){
       // etc.
```

Way less code, no need for an auxiliary method. Also a lot more efficient, because it avoids unnecessarily creating strings.

Comment: I appreciate your help :). I think in the for loop it has to be dish[row].length() with the brackets and in the if statement you've written if (lines[r].charAt(c).I don't know what you mean there, because we haven't defined "lines" anywhere..

Comment: They were typos. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have a small problem. In the part: "here ends the interesting part for you" there's an else with newGen[row] += dish[row].charAt(i), but we haven't defined an i. What can I do there?

Comment: Replace `i` with `col`.

Answer (score 4):

Everything you do inside the second function will have to be done in the first function. So just copy the code from function 2 into function 1:

```
public static String[] life(String[] dish){
String[] newGen= new String[dish.length];

//TODO: implement this functions
for(int row = 0; row < dish.length; row++){ // each row
    newGen[row]= "";
    for(int i = 0; i < dish[row].length(); i++){ // each char in the row
        String above = ""; // neighbors above
        String same = ""; // neighbors in the same row
        String below = ""; // neighbors below
        if(i == 0){ // all the way on the left
            // no one above if on the top row
            // otherwise grab the neighbors from above
            above = (row == 0) ? null : dish[row - 1].substring(i, i + 2);
            same = dish[row].substring(i + 1, i + 2);
            // no one below if on the bottom row
            // otherwise grab the neighbors from below
            below = (row == dish.length - 1) ? null : dish[row + 1].substring(i, i + 2);
        }else if(i == dish[row].length() - 1){//right
            // no one above if on the top row
            // otherwise grab the neighbors from above
            above = (row == 0) ? null : dish[row - 1].substring(i - 1, i + 1);
            same = dish[row].substring(i - 1, i);
            // no one below if on the bottom row
            // otherwise grab the neighbors from below
            below = (row == dish.length - 1) ? null : dish[row + 1].substring(i - 1, i + 1);
        }else{ // anywhere else
            // no one above if on the top row
            //otherwise grab the neighbors from above
            above = (row == 0) ? null : dish[row - 1].substring(i - 1, i + 2);
            same = dish[row].substring(i - 1, i) + dish[row].substring(i + 1, i + 2);
            //no one below if on the bottom row
            //otherwise grab the neighbors from below
            below = (row == dish.length - 1) ? null : dish[row + 1].substring(i - 1, i + 2);
        }

        // here is the interesting part for you:
        int neighbors = 0;
        if(above != null){//no one above
          for(char x: above.toCharArray()){ //each neighbor from above
            if(x == 'x') neighbors++; //count it if someone is here
          }
        }
        for(char x: same.toCharArray()){ //two on either side
          if(x == 'x') neighbors++;//count it if someone is here
        }
        if(below != null){ //no one below
          for(char x: below.toCharArray()){//each neighbor below
            if(x == 'x') neighbors++;//count it if someone is here
          }
        };
        //here ends the interesting part for you
        if(neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3){
            newGen[row]+= "o"; // If the amount of neighbors is < 2 or >3 neighbors -> they die
        }else if(neighbors == 3){
            newGen[row]+= "x"; // If the amount of neighbors is exactly 3 neighbors -> they spawn/live
        }else{
            newGen[row]+= dish[row].charAt(i); // 2 neighbors -> stay
        }
    }
}

return newGen;
```

}

Comment: You are a newbie, so lets reward you for the work of *answering* the question. Although I think the *real* answer would be to do the exact opposite of making un-readable code even more unreadable (by merging methods instead of further splitting up code).